# How to chose Bill-to and Ship-to field value via API in Microsoft Dynamics Nav?

Tags: php, api, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I need to setup value of fields "Ship-to" and "Bill-to"(see screenshot)). How I can do this in API?

I already read info in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/fin-graph/resources/dynamics_complextypes#postal-address) but I can't find info about this fields.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQjQ5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find only one answer: **you can't choose it via API**.

You can only choose it **manually on Sales order page**.